# Difference between 生活 and 生命

Tags: word-choice, word, synonyms

Both 生活 and 生命 mean "life". Both can be modified by "好" (好生活/好生命). Like any language, I don't believe two words ever mean the exact identical thing. If anybody could point me to the subtle (or not so subtle) differences between the two words, I would be most grateful. Thanks!

Comment: "生活" is the external situation where one lives while "生命" is a identity of every living creature.

Answer (score 5):

生活 is life as in "family life/private life/sex life/working life".
生命 is life as in "Cats are supposed to have nine lives/He lost his life in an accident"

Comment: They are totally different, though they share the same word "life" in English.

Comment: More precisely, 生活 is lifestyle. Also note that the word 命 alone means fate or destiny.

Comment: examples：生活：他们过着紧张忙碌的生活。她过的是安逸闲适的生活。（实用英汉词典）生命？ 按说猫有九条命,lost his life:战斗中阵亡了，也丢了性命，牺牲了,丧生，送了命（jukuu）

Comment: @PEMapModder 命 alone doesn't necessarily mean fate. It can mean fate / lifespan / life as in "he lost his life in an accident".

Comment: @PEMapModder 生活 does not directly mean _lifestyle_.

Comment: answer in dictionaries, e.g. **zdic** , some users found answer by examining e.g.jukuu's examples: **生命** :used in context of ～ and death 死亡隶属于生命，正与生一样, saving ～,挽救她的生命,～ span 生命期,～ has a limit, 生命有限,～ after death 他坚信死后仍有生命,～ at stake 生命安全受到威胁， **生活**  ： 生活风格，生活环境中，生活目标，生活的复杂，模拟现实生活，生活可以继续，in many contexts neither of 生命,生活 may be the appropriate C. equivalent for "life" .

Comment: @ltux when 命 is used _alone_. If it means _life_, it must be paired with other words, like 生命, 人命, but if alone, it should mean _fate_, like 命苦, 命好, which are two words, not one compound word. Of course, 命 can also mean order/command, but it is not related to this question.

Comment: @PEMapModder. It doesn't have to be paired with other words. Life as in "he lost his life in an accident" : 救命，一条命，丧了命. Lifespan: 短命. I guess the discussion will eventually fall into what constitute a *compound word*.

Answer (score 2):

生活 - everyday life.
生命 - from birth to death.